# Destructor for a linked-list node

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I have a `Node` class and a `List` class in my linked list. Do I need a destructor inside my `Node` class, or should I just use the destructor in my `List` class to delete all of the nodes?

Here's my .h so far:

```
class Node
{

public:

    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node();
    Node(int);
};

class List
{

private:

     Node* head;

public:

    List();
    List(List &a);
    ~List();
    //additional functions (insert, delete, etc)
};
```

Comment: Your code would be helpful...

Comment: Do you dynamically allocate any memory in Node? If yes you should de-allocate it in its destructor. Otherwise Node's guts will be cleared out when it gets out of scope. The same goes for Node objects in List, if they are dynamically allocated then you should destroy them in List's destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends how you create your linked list node. If you "new" it, then you have to call "delete" in order to free the memory. From your class definition it looks like you are not allocating anything in your constructor. If, in your constructor you allocate any memory, then you HAVE to deallocate it in your destructor.